# why is unresolved generic type legal in a generic?

Tags: swift, generics

Perhaps I'm being extremely dense, and I realize I'm supposed to know about this sort of thing, but I was taken by surprise by this:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    let value: T
    var wrapper: Wrapper? // ok
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
class Thing {
    var wrapper: Wrapper? // error
}
```

The error is that inside class Thing I have to resolve the Wrapper generic when I declare the type; I need to say, for instance,

```
var wrapper: Wrapper<String>?
```

Why is legal to declare that a property has type Wrapper plain and simple inside a Wrapper but not elsewhere? What makes the declaration inside Wrapper okay? Is it because the compiler just assumes that inside Wrapper, `Wrapper` means `Wrapper<T>`?

Comment: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/using-self-to-refer-to-enclosing-types/

Comment: @Jessy I think I knew about the `extension` bit, but this seems different somehow.

Comment: It’s outlived its usefulness for most cases. https://forums.swift.org/t/using-the-bare-name-of-a-generic-type-within-itself/24778

Comment: After many edits, I think I've distilled my answer down to something intelligible but not overly long.  Sorry if you tried to read it while I re-edited it so many times.  I should have written it offline.

Comment: @ChipJarred Nah, I do exactly the same thing: answer and then edit like crazy. Basically you're saying my guess is right; it is inferring that T is the same T. It's funny I never noticed this shortcut before.

Comment: @matt Yep, that's pretty much it.  The more interesting question is why you can sometimes refer to an unknown type by a protocol it conforms to, and why sometimes you can't.   That gets into `Self` and `associatedType` constraints, and on use of `some`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of `Wrapper`, `T` is known, as it's part of `Wrapper`'s definition, so use of `Wrapper` without specialization is implicitly assumed to be `Wrapper<T>`

In the case of `Thing`, there is no `T` defined, and even if there were, it would not be the same `T` as in `Wrapper`.  Think of it being analogous to these functions:

```swift
func foo(_ x: Int) {
   // x is known here
}

func bar() {
   // x is unheard of here.
}

func foobar(_ x: Int) {
   // x is known here, but it's not the same x as in foo
}
```

Of course the difference is that even `foo` has to refer to `x` explicitly, whereas `Wrapper` can infer `T` within its own definition.  In fact, if `Wrapper` wants to refer to another `Wrapper` that's specialized on a different type, it has to be explicit about it:

```swift
class Wrapper<T> {
   ...
   func someConversion<U>(otherWrapper: Wrapper<U>) {
   }
}
```

`Thing` on the other hand is declared outside of `Wrapper`, so it doesn't know about `T`.  So from its perspective

```swift
var wrapper: Wrapper?
```

is just as meaningless as

```swift
var values: Array?
```

The compiler can't create an array if it doesn't know the `Element` type.  Neither can it create your `Wrapper` without knowing what `T` is.